# Como creo una función que se ejecute al presionar un botón python telebot?

Tags: python, telegram

Como creo una función que se ejecute al presionar un botón y me diga que en tres minutos se ejecutara en python

```
import time
starttime = time.time()
            while True:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='Ya regresaste.')
                time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='Regresarás en 3 minutos.', reply_markup=principal_Kb())
```

Comment: Si las computadoras explotaran al intentar ejecutar códigos con problemas de indentación estoy seguro que todos prestarían más atención. Bromas a parte, me gustaría saber porqué haces todo esto `time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))`, ¿No es mejor hacer `time.sleep(180)` para esperar 3 minutos?

Comment: Solo coloque 1 min para probar xd, pero se queda enviando el mensaje siempre y  estoy intentando hacer que solo se ejecute cada vez que presionen un botón xd

Comment: si no quieres que se quede enviando siempre el mensaje, no lo pongas en un ciclo `while True` o usa una condición que conduzca a un `break` para abandonar el ciclo infinito en el momento que retengas oportuno.

Comment: Gracias me funciono  :D